# when does grep count and when does it not

Tags: grep

The manual page for `grep` says:

> `-c`, `--count`: Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines  for  each  input  file.

given:

```
# grep -R -c sleeping /proc/*/status
```

I get a list, not a count (as with):

```
# grep -R sleeping /proc/*/status | wc -l
```

What's up with `grep -c`?
What am I doing (in the commands above) to not get a count from it and having to use `wc -l` instead)?

Comment: `/proc/10871/status:1`? That is a count for each input file. Please [edit] in the output you're seeing, and what you expected.

Comment: yes Michael, that gave me a count for every file under /proc/*/* that contained 'sleeping' - but ... why grep -c wouldn't is the puzzler

Comment: That's what `grep -c` does (or actually `grep` all the time); that's what "matching lines for each input file" means. Is that the output you're seeing? "1" is the count.

Comment: Michael:
with grep -R -c sleeping /proc/*/status
I get 1 line of output (like ls, for each match)
just a sec and I'll put the outputs and my expects in the q
Thanks!

Comment: Michael, 
oops
matches for EACH file, got it now (looked at the output again as I was about to copy it (with an eye to your comment).
:n on every file opened my eyes and your comment re: /proc/10871/status:1
Thanks for your feedback ! :)
Make this an answer, if you like, and I'll check it off and close it

Comment: As an aside, I think `-R` is useless there, none of the `/proc/NNN/status` files are directories, so there's nothing to recurse into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -c` gives the count of matching lines for each input file separately (that's what your quote from the manual says, really):

```
$ grep -c user chmod.1 chown.1 
chmod.1:20
chown.1:5
```

So `chmod.1` has 20 matches, `chown.1` has 5.

The listing of file names works similarly here as with a normal grep, i.e. the file names are listed if there is more than one input file, but not if there is only one. At least in GNU grep, this can be modified with the `-H` and `-h` flags.

So,

```
$ grep -c user chmod.1
20
$ grep -cH user chmod.1
chmod.1:20
```

Answer (score 2):

For a total count, use a perhaps not so useless use of `cat` so that `grep` does not report per-file counts

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /proc/*/status | grep -c sleeping
171
-bash-4.2$ grep sleeping /proc/*/status | wc -l
171
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: interesting ...
it works fine with a 2>/dev/null on the cat

Comment: @iletras there's no standard error so the redirect is hiding nothing (unless the `cat` fails for some reason, then an error message might be hidden)

Comment: my bad @thrig! - I mistyped your code and read the result rather than re-read what I typed :(
ps ... nice cat :)